# news functionality in mediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

i need to add the "add news functionality" to my mediaWiki, where admin AND users will be able to add the news is there any extension to do that? or can someone please help me do that?

i am using mediaWiki 1.16

please help

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the News extension : http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:News

You will then be able to show news by selecting articles part of a given category :)

Comment: ...or even create a custom namespace like "News:" and only show new pages in that namespace.